# How do I find one particular file in a group of tarballs?

Tags: linux, unix

I know

```
tar tf singletarball.tar.gz | grep myfile.c
```

will work for an individual file.  I did try

```
ls *.gz | tar tf | grep myfile.c"
```

but that results in an error requiring the tar option to have a filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xargs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs):

```
ls *.tar.gz | xargs -n1 tar tzf | grep myfile.c
```